# How do you ask the age of a person in a picture?

Tags: tense, phrase-usage, past-tense, questions

I am confused between these two sentences :

1. How old are you in this picture?
2. How old were you in this picture?

Which one of these is correct or more accurate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*How old are you in this picture?* is OK (the picture shows you at a certain age).

If you use the past tense, it's better to say *How old were you when this picture was taken?*